# Код на Java для узнавания цвета пикселей

Tags: java, изображения, hex

Мне необходимо, чтобы программа брала изображение и проходила по каждому пикселю, выдавая hex код цвета пикселя.Как можно это реализовать? Искал в интернете что-либо о способах или библиотеках, но ничего не нашёл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    // The the pixel color information at 210, 20
    Color color = robot.getPixelColor(210, 20);

    // Print the RGB information of the pixel color
    System.out.println("Red   = " + color.getRed());
    System.out.println("Green = " + color.getGreen());
    System.out.println("Blue  = " + color.getBlue());
    System.out.println(String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue()));
}
```

К примеру так - данный код возьмет точку на вашем экране с координатами 210, 20
и определит его цвет в RGB и HEX

Comment: А так можно проверять изображения с камеры меняя в цикле x и y:
```color = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);``` ???

Comment: @ArthurAlunts таким образом получаем данные с любой точки экрана. Я так когда то кликер писал на одну игрушку )). Если вывод с камеры на экран есть, то в чем проблема?

Comment: проблема в том чтобы обрабатывать весь экран условными операторами за одну секунду и быстрее, так можно например я должен захватить картинку с видео на экране...

Comment: @ArthurAlunts, в чем проблема? Делаете скрин экрана и работаете с ним - BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize())); - вот вам экран.